# Hw can I assign a list as an attribute and retrieving the list in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using `Node.js` framework for coding.
To render a page I am sending some parameter in response one of those parameter is a list.

```
response.render("dashboard", {
                message: 'createAssociationMember',
                myList :[],
                flagForBulkUpload : 0
            });
```

In my `ejs` page I can directly use `myList` as a list to populate value in some table.

```
<% myList.forEach( function(userAssociation) { %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= userAssociation.associationId%></td>
            <td><%= userAssociation.userId%></td>
            <td><%= userAssociation.status%></td>
            <% if(userAssociation.errorMessage && userAssociation.errorMessage.length > 0){%>
            <td><span style="color: red;"><%= userAssociation.errorMessage%></span></td>
            <%} else {%>
            <td><span style="color: green;">Data is correct</span></td>
            <%}%>
          </tr>
          <% } )%>
```

But, I am trying to send this as a parameter to server side by sending this list as one of the parameter, I am notable to send it properly.

To do this, I have tried to assign this list to an attribute in button and tried to retrieve it while sending parameter.
I used

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" list_member="<%= myList%>"name="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="submitMemberList"> Submit </button>
```

But When I tried to look out on values it is not a list, even `typeof` function is returning it as a `string`.

To retrieve this, I tried

```
 $("#submitMemberList").on('click',function() {
          var listOfMembers = $(this).attr("list_member");
          console.log(listOfMembers);
          console.log("Type of "+typeof(listOfMembers));
});
```

Am I missing something ??

```
console.log(listOfMembers)
```

is printing values `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: At a glance. You need to remove the space between the word function and the parentheses.

Comment: `But When I tried to look out on values it is not a list,`  what is it instead? `typeof function is returning it as a string` that's what html element attributes are, strings, there's no getting around that

Comment: I can't see any code regarding `userAssociationList` - perhaps that's the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX is right, what you are getting is the expected behaviour. Then, if you want to transform this `String` into an `Array` you can use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) javascript function